# How to add custom script to vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this field

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-example">
```

with this jQuery

```
$('#datepicker-example').datepicker({});
```

How should I use my jQuery code in Vue component to get my input works properly?

`Script`

```
export default {
        data() {
          return {
               // my data
            }
          };
        },
        components: {
            // my components
        },
        methods: {
          //my methods
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not the best practice to use jQuery with Vue.

Comment: @dziraf what should i do?

Comment: There is plenty of DatePicker vue components, just choose one. Check this for components: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use datepicker in vue, it's best to wrap it into a component like so:

```
Vue.component('datepicker', {
    props: ['dateformat','defaultdate','minDate','maxDate'],
    template: '<input type="text" />',
    mounted: function() {
        var dateformat = this.dateformat;
        var defaultdate = this.defaultdate;
        $(this.$el).datepicker({
            minDate: this.minDate,
            maxDate: this.maxDate,
            dateFormat: dateformat,
            onClose: this.onClose,
            defaultDate: defaultdate
        });
    },
    methods: {
        onClose: function(date) {
            this.$emit('input', date);
        }
    }
});
```

Basically you make props for whatever settings you need, and the component can be used in any project.

usage:

```
 <datepicker v-model="input.date"></datepicker>
```

If you don't require jquery datepicker, but another library is possible i would recommend: http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/date-picker